# PostgreSQL 9.3: Crosstab query

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, crosstab

I have a table called as testing which is having four columns as shown below.

```
create table testing
(
cola varchar(10),
colb varchar(10),
colc varchar(10),
cold varchar(10)
);
```

Insertion of some rows:

```
insert into testing values('A1','City1','X1','Z1'),
              ('A2','City2','X2','Z2'),
              ('A3','City3','X3','Z3'),
              ('A4','City4','X4','Z4');
```

**Expected Result**: I want to show the result which looks like as shown below:

```
cola  City1  City2  City3  City4  colc  cold
--------------------------------------------
A1      1      0      0      0     X1    Z1
A2      0      1      0      0     X2    Z2
A3      0      0      1      0     X3    Z3
A4      0      0      0      1     X4    Z4
```

## My try:

I have tried with the following script but getting an error.

```
select * from crosstab
(
'select cola,colb,count(colb),colc,cold from testing group by 1,2,4,5 order by 1,2,4,5',
'select distinct colb from testing'
)
as t
(
    cola varchar(10),City1 integer,City2 integer,City3 integer,City4 integer,colc varchar(10),cold varchar(10)
);
```

**Error Details**:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "City1"
```

Comment: what's the relation between `A1` and `City1`?

Comment: @Kokizzu, That is just an example.I can say that `A1` will be the product code and `City1` will be the city which has been sold out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want?

```
select x1.*, x2.colc, x2.cold from crosstab
( $$select x1.cola, x2.colb,
     CASE WHEN x1.colb = x2.colb THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    FROM testing x1 CROSS JOIN testing x2 
  $$
) AS x1( cola VARCHAR(10), City1 INT, City2 INT, City3 INT, City4 INT)
LEFT JOIN testing x2 ON x1.cola = x2.cola;
```

Result:

```
 cola | city1 | city2 | city3 | city4 | colc | cold 
------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+------
 A1   |     1 |     0 |     0 |     0 | X1   | Z1
 A2   |     0 |     1 |     0 |     0 | X2   | Z2
 A3   |     0 |     0 |     1 |     0 | X3   | Z3
 A4   |     0 |     0 |     0 |     1 | X4   | Z4
```

Comment: How to get distinct values and count of `colb`. If there is same multiple values in `cola`. For example if I insert the above rows 2 times.

Comment: just replace `testing` within `crostab` with `(SELECT cola, count(colb) AS colb FROM testing)`

Comment: I usually use server side programming language to do this, since the query are not flexible (for example when you add more City).. or sometimes I generate the `sql` using a program so it could be more flexible..

Comment: Yeah! Exactly. When there is an situation that city's are not fixed rather they are dynamic. They may changes as per the entries are made. I will check your commented script after an hour. Right now I am on smart phone so will not be able to check it.

Comment: what programming language do you use on the server side?

Comment: ,I use language Plpgsql.